# STP with Vlan, uses normal configuration only?

Tags: vlan

In a network with redundant vlan trunks, does the STP run normally on the trunks or does it need to do any more configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: The point of STP is that it creates a single path back to the root, so it chooses one link among multiple links to use, and it blocks the other links in the multiple links. You could possibly use some type of link aggregation to fool STP into using them all.

Comment: I really liked your idea. If I put all uplinks on the same port-channel, does that not eliminate the need to use STP?

Comment: No, STP can save you when mistakes are made. The port-channel just fools STP into thinking you have a single link for all the links in the channel. Never disable STP unless you have a very good reason, and you really know what you are doing and understand the risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several versions of STP: classic STP (obsolete), RSTP, MSTP (all IEEE) and the proprietary Cisco variants (R)PVST(+).

Cisco's aside, classic STP and RSTP are completely VLAN-agnostic. They block redundant links entirely on the basis of a "flat" network - as if no VLANs were used. Even if you distribute your VLAN trunks so that there are no actual loops, (R)STP still blocks (seemingly) redundant links regardlessly (actually breaking L2 connectivity) - so you'd actually be better off without STP.

MSTP works the exact same way by default *but* it allows you to create independent MSTP instances, each building its own spanning tree. If you group your VLANs accordingly, you can make use of redundant links that you couldn't use with (R)STP.

For instance, take two switches running four VLANs 1, 2, 3, 4. With two links between the switches and all VLANs trunked on each link, (R)STP blocks one of the links - it's effectively useless until the primary links fails.

With MSTP, you can group VLAN 1 & 2 to one instance, and 3 & 4 to the other. Since each instance creates its own spanning tree, you can use port priorities to move the 1&2 instance to the first port, and the 3&4 instance to the second. You still have full redundancy but you've got two productive links.

RSTP interacts with MSTP without problems but only in the default instance.

Comment: We have 2 main suppliers, Juniper and Cisco. I didn't know about MSTP, and it looks like it's the best version so far.
There are several suppliers that don't support MSTP. How to solve this problem ?
What's best version of STP, that works with VLAN or that don't use VLAN ?

Comment: RSTP doesn't care about VLANs at all. If you want to leverage redundant connections, multiple MSTP intances is the only vendor-independent way. Some vendors also support RPVST+ (that creates independent trees for each VLAN) but that may result in a lock-in situation.

Comment: The IEEE spanning-tree protocols (STP, RSTP, MSTP) are carefully-designed for backward compatibility.  For this reason, I prefer to use MSTP instead of the Cisco-proprietary protocols.  If I need to use some switches (often at the edge of a network) that don't support MSTP, it's no problem; MSTP works fine with STP/RSTP switches.  *What doesn't work fine* is some mixes of Cisco-proprietary xSTP protocols and standard ones.  Like @Zac67 mentions, you can get locked in to one vendor if you use their protocol instead of the standard ones.